# In BigQuery, is there a way to increase the number of output sink for a stage?

Tags: performance, google-bigquery

When I tried to improve my query performance, I found that the slot utilization was very low, where only 100 slots were used for a long time (2000 slots are the limit).

By investigating the log file, I found the bottleneck stage's 'parallelInputs' was only 80. However the number of rows of the input was about 100 million, and there were no duplicated value. Therefore I think the query planner should increase the output sink of the stage before the bottleneck stage.

Is there a way to encourage the query planner to increase an output sink?

==============================

I have resolved my performance problem with "UNION" method of the answer.

In my case, I used subqueries instead of a view like the following

```
with slow_stage as (
  ...
), multiple_read as (
select
  *
from slow_stage where MOD(key, 3)=0

union all
select
  *
from slow_stage where MOD(key, 3)=1
...
)
```

I expected a three-hold improvement. However, the improvement was more than a five-hold because of the increase of the output sinks of the slow_stage. Previously, slow_stage had only 80 output sinks. After applying "UNION" method, it had over 1000 outputs sinks.

I thought the number of output sinks depends on the size and shape of the output. (I refered "Google BigQuery: The Definitive Guide")
In this case I didn't change the output of the slow_stage, so I don't know a reason of the major improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hack which you may be able to use with caution:

Below query split `yourDataset.yourTable` table into 16 shards by value of `col1`, it doesn't increase cost because BigQuery charge by size of the tables it scans.

Again, use it with caution for the hack may not be effective in the future.

```sql
CREATE VIEW yourdataset.yourJoinedTable AS (
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = '0' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = '1' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = '2' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = '3' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = '4' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = '5' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = '6' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = '7' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = '8' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = '9' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = 'a' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = 'b' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = 'c' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = 'd' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = 'e' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourDataset.yourTable WHERE SUBSTR(col1, 0, 1) = 'f'
);

SELECT ...
FROM yourdataset.yourJoinedTable;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have resolved my performance problem with "UNION" method.